# How to get a button with text to show up in GridLayout

Tags: android

I have a 3X3 game board that is represented by buttons.  The individual squares show up when I launch my app, but I cannot find why the button to start a new game does not.  I'm providing the code from MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Declare class variables and initialize the board
    String square1,
            square2,
            square3,
            square4,
            square5,
            square6,
            square7,
            square8,
            square9,
            newgame;

    // Handle button objects 
    Button square1_button;
    Button square2_button;
    Button square3_button;
    Button square4_button;
    Button square5_button;
    Button square6_button;
    Button square7_button;
    Button square8_button;
    Button square9_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assign button objects to ids
        square1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r1c1_button);
        square2_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r1c2_button);
        square3_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r1c3_button);
        square4_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r2c1_button);
        square5_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r2c2_button);
        square6_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r2c3_button);
        square7_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r3c1_button);
        square8_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r3c2_button);
        square9_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r3c3_button);
    }

    void resetBoard()
    {

        String button1_str = square1_button.getText().toString();
        String button2_str = square2_button.getText().toString();
        String button3_str = square3_button.getText().toString();
        String button4_str = square4_button.getText().toString();
        String button5_str = square5_button.getText().toString();
        String button6_str = square6_button.getText().toString();
        String button7_str = square7_button.getText().toString();
        String button8_str = square8_button.getText().toString();
        String button9_str = square9_button.getText().toString();

        square1 = button1_str;
        square2 = button2_str;
        square3 = button3_str;
        square4 = button4_str;
        square5 = button5_str;
        square6 = button6_str;
        square7 = button7_str;
        square8 = button8_str;
        square9 = button9_str;

//      square1 = "";
//      square2 = "";
//      square3 = "";
//      square4 = "";
//      square5 = "";
//      square6 = "";
//      square7 = "";
//      square8 = "";
//      square9 = "";   

        // Mark the first three squares with an X
        square1 = "X";
        square2 = "X";
        square3 = "X";
    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.  On a side note, the first three squares are not being set with an "X" so I think my problem is before that line of code.

This is my layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:rowCount="6"
    tools:context="com.jtryon.tictactoe.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r1c1_button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r1c2_button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r1c3_button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2c1_button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2c2_button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2c3_button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r3c1_button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r3c2_button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r3c3_button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newgame_text"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newgame_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button_reset"
        android:onClick="resetBoard" />      

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reset your button text you should do something like that:

```
Button btn_reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);

btn_reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resetBoard()
        }
    });
```

//Now after onCreate() replace your resetBoard() method with mine...

```
void resetBoard()
    {
        square1_button.settext("");

        square2_button.settext("");

        square3_button.settext("");

        square4_button.settext("");

        square5_button.settext("");

        square6_button.settext("");

        square7_button.settext("");

        square8_button.settext("");

        square9_button.settext("");

    }
```

replace my resetBoard() method with yours and you are done :)

**Update:**

If you really want to use `GridView` you should create `buttons` dynamically by making `Adapter` for `GridView` and set `LayoutParams`

I suggest you should do in your xml setting up all buttons using `TableLayout` like below

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r1c1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r1c2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r1c3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r2c1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r2c2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r2c3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r3c1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r3c2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r3c3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you need an onClickListener when you have an onClick defined in the xml?  I thought they did the same thing unless it is suggested to create a listener.  I am still trying to figure out why the button is not showing up in the layout.  Thanks for the help with the resetBoard method.